# Jenkins is getting permission denied errors when running maven

Tags: tomcat, maven-2, jenkins, redhat, selenium-webdriver

I'm running Jenkins on a redhat linux box. My build is a maven 2.2.1 project that contains selenium tests. I've got the same setup on a ubuntu box which works fine, but when I attempt to invoke the same top-level maven command on my redhat VM I get the following error.

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Unable to create file for report: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied); nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied); nested exception is 
org.apache.maven.surefire.report.ReporterException: Unable to create file for report: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied); nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied)
org.apache.maven.surefire.report.ReporterException: Unable to create file for report: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied); nested exception is        
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/selenium/workspace/target/surefire-reports/com.MyComp.bio.PreferencesTest.txt (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.AbstractFileReporter.testSetStarting(AbstractFileReporter.java:57)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.ReporterManager.testSetStarting(ReporterManager.java:219)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.
```

In attempting to solve this problem I've restart Jenkins

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

but it persists. Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Check the owner / permissions on the directory that Jenkins is attempting to write to. The user that Jenkins is running under must be able to write to that directory or you will get a permission denied error

Comment: @renab your suggestion did allow jenkins to get past the permission errors, but the permissions between the ubuntu and redhat boxes had been the same when I was getting the error. Again a chmod a+rw to the files in question might be a work around, though it seems like I'm still missing something.

Comment: Is Jenkins running under the same user on Both the Ubuntu and Red Hat boxes?

If so, does a ls -lrt show that the Jenkins user owns the directories that it is attempting to write to?

Ownership is just as important as permissions in this case as the permissions can be correct for the owner to write to a directory but if the user writing is not the owner it can be denied permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ls -al` to display permissions of files.

See [this link](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html) for more information.

Read the service startup script to check the name of the user that Jenkins is running as.

`less /etc/init.d/jenkins`

You may have manually installed jenkins to a Java EE container such as tomcat6.
If this is the case, you should use:

`less /etc/init.d/tomcat6`